# Is the distribution of the minimum of two other distributions a mixture distribution? Or is there a better term?

Tags: distributions, terminology, mixture-distribution

This is a terminology question motivated by a review that I got on a paper. In the following I believe that $y$ would be considered to be distributed according to a *mixture distribution*:

$$y \sim \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  f_1(\theta_1)  & \mbox{with } p ~ \mbox{probability} \\
  f_2(\theta_2)  & \mbox{with } (1 - p) ~ \mbox{probability}
 \end{array}
\right. $$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are probability distributions. **But would it be correct to say that $x$ is also distributed according to a mixture distribution?**

$$ x \sim \text{min}(z_1,z_2) \\
   z_1 \sim f_1(\theta_1) \\
   z_2 \sim f_2(\theta_2)$$

If not, is there a better term? Or, at least, a general term for a distribution that is *some* combination of two other distributions?

(I mean, $x$ is certainly the result of "mixing together" $f_1$ and $f_2$ in some way, but I don't know if this is enough to call it a mixture... :)

Comment: I believe there is no general term for "some combination" of distributions simply because the concept is far too broad to be useful.

Comment: I would say most latent variable models qualify for your "mixing" behaviour, but this does not help much because about everything is a latent variable model!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that counts as a mixture, no.

A mixture distribution draws from among a collection of distributions according to a random variable from another distribution (as in your first example, though of course they can be more complex than Bernoulli mixtures, including continuous mixtures).

The $\min$ case doesn't seem to have the characteristics I'd normally understand as being a mixture.

Comment: So do you have a suggestion for what to call it? A compound distribution? A hybrid distribution? A blend distribution? :)

Comment: No, I don't, sorry. If I had been able to think of a good specific term, I'd mention it. If I find one I'll let you know.

Comment: The best I could think of was "the distribution of the minimum" ... which is no help.